# Isomorphism between $U$ and $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Two vector spaces are called isomorphic if an isomorphism exists between them, and we write $V \cong W$.

A mapping $$f: V\rightarrow W$$ is called an isomorphism if it is linear and bijective.

Show that if $U$ is vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ finitedimensional, then $U\cong \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

Now I know that a finitedimensional vector space has a basis with finite amount of vectors. And I know what linear and bijective is, but im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You must add the condition that $\;U\;$ is a vector space *over* $\;\Bbb R\;$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Choose a basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_n\}\;$ of $\;U\;$ , and then define

$$Tu_i:=e_i\in\Bbb R^n\;\;,\;\;e_i:=i\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ldots\\1\\\ldots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

and expand definition of $\;T\;$ by linearity. Check it is a linear transformation and bijective

Comment: I dont understand the notation $$Tu_i:=e_i\in\Bbb R^n\;\;,\;\;e_i:=i\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}0\\\ldots\\1\\\ldots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: *What* you don't understand? $\;Tu_i\;$ is the transf. $\;T\;$ applied at the vector $\;u_i\;$ and mapping it to $\;e_i\;$ , which is the $\;i$- th element in the canonical basis of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ .

Comment: How would I show $T(u_1+u_2)=T(u_1)+T(u_2);\ for all (u_1,u_2) ;\in U$?

Comment: @joog This is what is meant by "extend the definition by linearity": take any $\;u\in U\;$ and write it as a linear combination of the basis we chose: $$u=\sum_{k=1}^n a_iu_i\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb R\;$$ and now on this define $$Tu:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_iTu_i:=\sum_{i=1}^na_ie_i$$ It's now a simple exercise to show $\;T\;$ is actually a linear transformation, and since it maps basis to basis it is, in this case, an isomorphism.

Comment: I see how this would be bijective, because the basis to basis is one to one. But for $(u,v) \in\ U$ , how would you prove it is linear, that is, $T(u+v)= T(u) + T(v)$ . To me it doesn't seem trivial that $T(u+v)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_iTu_i + \sum_{i=1}^n a_iTv_i:$ . Could you show this linear property?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If a linear transformation takes basis into basis then is an isomorphism.

Take $\{v_1,\ldots, v_n\} \subset U$ you may define a transformation $A : \mathbb R^n \to U$ that takes each $v = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ and

$$Av = \alpha_1v_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n$$

And $Ae_1 = v_1, \ldots , Ae_n = v_n$, where $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a canonical basis.

Comment: Feel free to ask.

Comment: I dont understand this hint, why would I define a transformation $$A : \mathbb R^n \to U$$ and not the other way around?

Comment: It's same if you seek an isomorphism.

Comment: I forgot, thanks! Now let me see if I can figure out your hint.

Comment: Great! Don't hesitate in asking.

Comment: Okay, so you define a transformation A, a matrix. Matrix multiplication is linear so that makes sense. Now I dont see how you use this matrix multiplication and $$Ae_n$$.

Comment: See $A$ is a transformation defined as it was takes every vector of the basis in $\mathbb R^n$ to a vector in the basis of $U$, you just need to write it down to see.